# Grammar of "How many 2-digit even NUMBERS can be formed by USING DIGITS 1, 3, 4 and 6? (Each NUMBER can be USED only once.)"

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

It is my kid's problem.

[image]

I began to wonder about the Grammar of this problem:

- In English, use "Each NUMBER can be USED only once." or "Repetition of digits is not allowed?"
- Right Grammar "How many 2-digit even NUMBERS can be formed by USING DIGITS 1, 3, 4 and 6?(Each NUMBER can be USED only once.)" or "How many 2-digit even NUMBERS can be formed by USING DIGITS 1, 3, 4 and 6 (Each NUMBER can be USED only once.)?"
- "Number" word in "Each NUMBER can be USED only once." mean NUMBER or DIGIT?

If grammar of this problem is right, the result is 6 numbers?

Comment: Six is the correct answer in how I interpret the question.  $14,16,34,36,46,64$.  The count achieved perhaps even faster by saying "pick the units digit from the even options, then pick a different digit for the tens digit" giving $3\times 2=6$ outcomes.

Comment: Thanks @JMoravitz. I wonder about the GRAMMAR, if write "pick the units digit from the even options, then pick a different digit for the tens digit" i understand, but i want to know, can we use "Each NUMBER can be USED only once."  in official math test? or we have to use "Repetition of digits is not allowed?", i try to google but did not see any results of "Each NUMBER can be USED only once." used in math test.

Comment: They mean the same thing to me... what do you think the difference is between them?

Comment: If write "the digits are not be repeated within a number" i also understand, but "Each NUMBER can be USED only once." i understand that it is include 44 or 66 in result, because they are NUMBER. Because i am Vietnamese, so i really want to know in English, it is used "Each DIGIT can be USED only once." or "Each NUMBER can be USED only once." is right.

Comment: Each digit can be used only once would have been clearer.

Comment: Thanks @N.F.Taussig, in Grammar i see we have to use "," ".", "?", so i also want to know: Right Grammar "How many 2-digit even NUMBERS can be formed by USING DIGITS 1, 3, 4 and 6?(Each NUMBER can be USED only once.)" or "How many 2-digit even NUMBERS can be formed by USING DIGITS 1, 3, 4 and 6 (Each NUMBER can be USED only once.)?". The "?" is last of sentence is right?

Comment: The question should have been expressed as "How many $2$-digit even numbers can be formed by using the digits $1, 3, 4$ and $6$ if repetition of digits is not permitted?"  The author should not have enclosed a necessary condition in a parenthetical remark.

Comment: Thanks @N.F.Taussig, so i have last question, in English: "if repetition of digits is not permitted" same "if repetition of digits is not permitted within each 2-digits number"?

Comment: "if repetition of digits is not permitted within each 2-digit number" is more precise.